# Throwing the correct exceptions while performing CRUD operations in Spring/Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Suppose I am trying to add an entity to table using hibernate, before adding in my DAO I check if it already exist and if already exists I return null object or else I return the added entity ID.

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public T addEntity(@RequestBody State state) {
    T response = null;
    try {
        response = getService().add(state);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();


    }
    return response;

}
```

But when an null is returned I want to show the correct HTTP error code 400, is there any way I can do that in spring, instead of returning null? Thanks!

EDIT:

I tried some thing like this:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public T addEntity(@RequestBody String message,
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse) throws Exception {
    T response = null;
    try {
        response = getService().add(message);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        httpResponse.setStatus(409);
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new Exception("State already exists, Error 409");
    }
    return response;

}
```

but it gives out an exception as "Error 500 State already exists, Error 409"

Comment: why not return zero instead of null? Another option is to extend the protocol and return the reason in rssponse. Also you can return ResponseEntity in the latest versions of spring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just manually set it directly:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public T addEntity(@RequestBody State state, HttpServletResponse httpResponse) {
    T response = null;
    try {
        response = getService().add(state);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        httpResponse.setStatus(400);
        e.printStackTrace();


    }
    return response;

}
```

Comment: I think this is going to be a silly question and related to java rather than spring. so when the add method is called from the controller, then in the service I check is the object already exists, if it exist I want to throw error 409 for conflict.

Comment: throw a more specific exception?

Comment: create a subclass of Exception like DuplicateRecordException so you can create a separate catch block for it and set the code

Comment: Thanks I will figure it out!

Comment: Well, you changed the behaviour from returning null to throwing an exception, so it is different. :)  In that case use `@ExceptionHandler` with `@ResponseStatus`

Comment: Thanks a lot I think I should figure this out!